# Cypress data attribute doesn't show up in angular dom

Tags: angular, angular-material, cypress, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to implement Cypress into my angular project with data-cy attributes, but they act very inconsistent. In some places the attribute does show in the dom, but in other places it doesn't.

Example where it doesn't show:

```html
<mat-radio-button
   *ngFor="let opt of question.options"
   [attr.data-cy]="question.key + '-' + opt.key"
   [value]="opt.key">
   {{opt.value}}
</mat-radio-button>
```

The value attribute does show, so somethings work. I've tried different handles like removing the brackets, removing `attr.` (but I'm aware this shouldn't work at all), and giving a different value as only a string saying `test`

Example where it does work:

```html
<fa-icon class="logoutButton" [attr.data-cy]="'profile-button'"></fa-icon>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the libraries restrict attributes to their published API's, but you can always use `arialabel` instead of `data-cy` since the major libraries will all support screen readers.

The attribute appears on the outermost element.

**Source**

```html
<mat-radio-button ariaLabel="test2" [value]="2">Select me</mat-radio-button>
```

**HTML**

```html
<mat-radio-button 
  arialabel="test2" 
  class="mat-radio-button mat-accent mat-radio-checked" 
  ng-reflect-value="2"
  ...
```

**Test**

```js
cy.get('mat-radio-button[arialabel="test2"]')
```

---

Reference [MatRadioButton](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/api#MatRadioButton)

> @Input('aria-label')
> ariaLabel: string
>
> Used to set the 'aria-label' attribute on the underlying input element.

**Notes**

- the HTML attribute has all lowercase chars `arialabel` even though the input attribute has camel-case
- `aria-label` is shown in the docs for use with the decorator `@Input('aria-label')`, but is not the form to use in the attribute

[image]

Of course, with `ng-for` you would use a unique key like `ariaLabel="question.key + '-' + opt.key"`

Comment: The aria-label sadly also doesn't show up in the dom

Comment: @JanessaLabeur have you tried `aria-label` instead of `arialabel`?

Comment: @JanessaLabeur you are mistaken. I've added more details.

Comment: @Fody Thanks, I've indeed tried aria-label, but this didn't work, the camelCase does work

Comment: Yes, `aria-label` is shown in the docs only for use with the decorator `@Input('aria-label')`. It's confusing, but easy to test with a little experimentation.